# In Neo4j, can one find all nodes whose relationships are a superset of another node's relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the following contrived database:

```
CREATE (a:Content {id:'A'}),
  (b:Content {id:'B'}),
  (c:Content {id:'C'}),
  (d:Content {id:'D'}),
  (ab:Container {id:'AB'}),
  (ab2:Container {id:'AB2'}),
  (abc:Container {id:'ABC'}),
  (abcd:Container {id:'ABCD'}),
  ((ab)-[:CONTAINS]->(a)),
  ((ab)-[:CONTAINS]->(b)),
  ((ab2)-[:CONTAINS]->(a)),
  ((ab2)-[:CONTAINS]->(b)),
  ((abc)-[:CONTAINS]->(a)),
  ((abc)-[:CONTAINS]->(b)),
  ((abc)-[:CONTAINS]->(c)),
  ((abcd)-[:CONTAINS]->(a)),
  ((abcd)-[:CONTAINS]->(b)),
  ((abcd)-[:CONTAINS]->(c)),
  ((abcd)-[:CONTAINS]->(d))
```

Is there a query that can detect all `Container` node pairs where one `CONTAINS` either a superset of or the same `Content` nodes as the other `Container` node?

For my example database, I would want the query to return:

```
(ABCD) is a superset of (ABC), (AB), and (AB2)
(ABC) is a superset of (AB), and (AB2)
(AB) and (AB2) contain the same nodes
```

If cypher is unsuitable for this but another query language is well suited to it, or if Neo4j is unsuitable for this but another database is well suited to it, I'd appreciate input on that as well.

[image: Visualization of the sample database]

**Answer query performance** (as of 2017-02-28T21:56Z)

I am not experienced enough yet with Neo4j or graph DB querying to analyze the performance of the answers, and I have not yet constructed my large data set for a more meaningful comparison, but I thought I'd run each with the PROFILE command and list the DB hit cost.  I omitted the timing data as I could not make it consistent or meaningful with such a small data set.

- stdob--: 129 total db hits
- Dave Bennett: 46 total db hits
- InverseFalcon: 27 total db hits

Comment: Both Dave Bennett's and stdob--'s answers seem to give me the result which I requested, thank you.  I've upvoted both and will award an answer once I've tried them on a larger data set, since I'm forced to pick one.

Comment: About how many Container nodes are there in the larger data set?

Comment: I haven't assembled it yet (that's going to take some doing and is next on my agenda now that I know I have viable tools to accomplish the latter calculations).  However, 70,000 Containers seems a realistic estimate.  That with Contents per Container ranging from a few to a few hundred, but probably 30 on average.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Get contents for each container
MATCH (SS:Container)-[:CONTAINS]->(CT:Content)
      WITH SS, 
           collect(distinct CT) as CTS
// Get all container not equal SS
MATCH (T:Container) 
      WHERE T <> SS
// For each container get their content
MATCH (T)-[:CONTAINS]->(CT:Content)
      // Test if nestd
      WITH SS, 
      CTS, 
      T, 
      ALL(ct in collect(distinct CT) WHERE ct in CTS) as test 
      WHERE test = true
RETURN SS, collect(T)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a first attempt. I am sure this can use some refinement but this should get you going.

```
// find the containers and their contents
match (n:Container)-[:CONTAINS]->(c:Content)

// group the contents per container
with n as container, collect(c.id) as contents

// combine the continers and their contents
with collect(container{.id, contents: contents}) as containers

// loop through the list of containers
with containers, size(containers) as container_size
unwind range(0, container_size -1) as i
unwind range(0, container_size -1) as j

// for each container pair compare the contents
with containers, i, j
where i <> j
and all(content IN containers[j].contents WHERE content in containers[i].contents)
with containers[i].id as superset, containers[j].id as subset
return superset, collect(subset) as subsets
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach I would use, after getting Containers and their collected Contents, is to filter down which Containers are compared to each other by the count of their contents, and then run [apoc.coll.containsAll() from APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) to filter for supersets/coequal sets. Lastly, you can compare the counts of contents to figure out if it's a superset or a coequal set, then collect.

Something like this:

```
match (con:Container)-[:CONTAINS]->(content)
with con, collect(content) as contents
with collect({con:con, contents:contents, size:size(contents)}) as all
unwind all as first
unwind all as second
with first, second
where first <> second and first.size >= second.size
with first, second
where apoc.coll.containsAll(first.contents, second.contents)
with first, 
 case when first.size = second.size and id(first.con) < id(second.con) then second end as same, 
 case when first.size > second.size then second end as superset
with first.con as container, collect(same.con) as sameAs, collect(superset.con) as supersetOf
where size(sameAs) > 0 or size(supersetOf) > 0
return container, sameAs, supersetOf
order by size(supersetOf) desc, size(sameAs) desc
```